# Meaning of "credit"

Tags: credit, terminology

From [Wikipedia - Credit (Finance)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_%28finance%29):

> Credit is the trust which allows one party to provide resources to
>   another party where that second party does not reimburse the first
>   party immediately (thereby generating a debt), but instead arranges
>   either to repay or return those resources (or other materials of equal
>   value) at a later date. The resources provided may be financial (e.g.
>   granting a loan), or they may consist of goods or services (e.g.
>   consumer credit). Credit encompasses any form of deferred payment.
>   Credit is extended by a creditor, also known as a lender, to a debtor,
>   also known as a borrower.

So credit is the trust of seller on buyer when seller delivers now
and buyer will pay some time later.

In some transactions, there are negative charges named `credits`
which reduce the overall charge. For example, in tax form 1040,
there are tax credits, and in a utility bill, there may be some
credits too.

I wonder if the concepts of credit in the two above cases are totally different and unrelated? To me, they seem so.

Comment: Those are two different uses of the word and are not related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking at the "wrong" credit. Here's the [Wikipedia article about the *bookkeeping*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debits_and_credits) (vs the Finance, that you've quoted) term.